# How to simulate iPhone sleeping (uncharged) in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios

I'm try to use the iOS simulator to debug a websocket issue.

On a phone (that is not being charged), safari websockets are closed in about 30s after the phone has been put to sleep. They stay alive much longer when the phone is powered.

It looks as though the simulator simulates the charging mode. How can I simulate sleeping without a power supply, such that the websocket is forcibly closed by Safari?